# Execute function on new page with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to open a new page (let's call this page2) from page1 and execute an ajax call on this new page. The ajax code is already present on page2, I just want to use it.

So I have a button in page1 to trigger this.

```
  $('.job_more_info').click(function(){
    var newpage = window.open("./jobs.php");
    newpage.changeJobInformation('1');
  })
```

But this fail with `TypeError: newpage.changeJobInformation is not a function`

I also tried to move the ajax code from page2 to page1. But I have the same error

### EDIT

I tried this

```
  $('.job_more_info').click(function(){
    var newpage = window.open("./jobs.php");
    newpage.onload = changeJobInformation('1');
  })
```

But the error tell me

> ReferenceError: changeJobInformation is not defined

Are you sure I can use a function from page2 ?

I also tried to rewrite a function directly from page1 and this is working. But this function change the HTML content of a div. So the div is changed on page1 instead of page2.

If I can not use the function from page2, how to use a JQuery selector to point another page ?

```
newpage.$('right').html(data)
```

?

---

Comment: Do you have to wait for the page to `load` before trying to call the method?

Comment: The error message says `newpage.document.changeJobInformation` but your code says `newpage.changeJobInformation`. Are you sure that is your actual code?

Comment: the problem is here that your newpage is probably not loaded yet when you are trying to fire that function. I guess you could check if you can get to the load event though ;)

Comment: This might not be possible at all due to security constraints (this is a guess, but imagine what coulde be done otherwise...)

Comment: Are you trying this locally? Then it is a security problem + probably the fact that the JS on the pop up page has not loaded yet

Comment: @Alex I use this locally. I will be the only one to use this so I do not really care about security problem. I edited my post for the onload problem

Comment: This could theoretically only work if you served both .html files from the same domain and with http:// and not file:// protocol BUT to be honest I can not get it to work either ;) With security problems I meat what the browser allows and does not allow. Each browser has build in security checks like the same-origin-policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally wrote the function on page1 and execute it on page2 with this code

```
  $('.job_more_info').click(function(){
    var newpage = window.open("./jobs.php");
    newpage.onload = function(){//myFunction}
  })
```